# Subtracting months from date using Redshift

Tags: sql, date, select, amazon-redshift, transform

I know I can use dateadd to add an interval to a date, what about subtracting, would I just use a negative number? Here is an example:

```
select "date_table"."id_date" >= date_trunc('month', dateadd(month,-18, current_date)) 
from "date_table"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what about subtracting, would I just use a negative number?

Yes. This works:

```
dateadd(month, -18, current_date)
```

You can also use `add-months()`:

```
add_months(current_date, -18)
```

Or interval litterals:

```
current_date - interval '18 months'
current_date - interval '1 year, 6 months'
```